# Webpage dropdown menu with select box events

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I need to implement a scroll-able drop down menu with select box features like hover on key press in web page.

For example:
My drop-down menu contains some 100 elemnts,
Apple
Ant
Ball
Orange
....

The menu must be scroll-able.
if I press 'A' the 'Apple' should get hover.
Again if I press 'A' Ant should get hover.
Up and down arrows should hover to previous and next elements.
I don't need a text box as in "select".

Please advice me a better way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand pefectly what you are looking for but an Angular ui-select might just be a simple option here.

Angular ui-select example
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

```
<ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" style="min-width: 300px;" title="Choose a person">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="person in ctrl.people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
  <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  <small>
    email: {{person.email}}
    age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  </small>
</ui-select-choices>
```

The closest thing I can think of within jQuery would be their autocomplete input, but it does not seems like the kind of cmoplexity you are looking for
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/